# Trying to make a rectangle move in canvas when a key is pressed but it will not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  canvas.addEventListener("keydown", doKeyDown, false);

  var context = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
  context.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 30);

  var canvasWidth = myCanvas.width;
  var canvasHeight = myCanvas.height;

  var x = 100;
  var y = 100;

  function doKeyDown(e) {       
    switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 87:
      y = y - 10;
      context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
      break;
    case 83:
      y = y + 10;
      context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);   
      break;
    case 65:
      x = x - 10;
      context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
  break;
    case 68:
      x = x + 10;
      context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);       
      break;
    }
  }

  function clearCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  }

});
```

What should happen is when W/A/S/D are pressed the rectangle will "move". Nothing happens though and I'm unsure why. I've tried using a different name for 'e' which made no difference of course. I keep looking for spelling errors. No luck.

Comment: did you try either, setting tabindex on the canvas - eg. `<canvas id="myCanvas" tabindex="0"></canvas>`, or binding the event listener to `document.body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly for me. I tested it in jsfiddle and works perfectly when the canvas has focus.

http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/c2Caj/

Just remember to use your `clearCanvas()` function before you redraw the rectangle.

**EDIT:** Updated my jsfiddle so the canvas gets immediate focus. Also added arrow key support.

Comment: @mvw The canvas is created in HTML. `<canvas id="myCanvas" tabindex="0"></canvas>`. Javascript isn't needed to instantiate it.

Comment: I forgot tabindex="0" in my canvas tag. It works now with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is atypo in your code. You are storing a reference to the canvas in the variable canvas, but everywhere you are using myCanvas

Comment: myCanvas is the id of the <canvas> in the html. Should I be using the same name for the canvas variable and the canvas tag id?

Answer (score 1):

### Focus

I have tried your example in @Spedwards jsfiddle and it worked once I clicked the canvas element, so as @Spedwards noted, the canvas having focus is crucial.

You might try to attach the key event handler to some parent element, e.g. the document window itself, if you want to make it work without giving focus to the canvas first.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", doKeyDown, false);
```

### Two References for the Canvas Element

I learned from your question and @Spedwards this interesting browser behaviour, which I was not aware of before (or forgot it in the meantime :-)

> 14.7 Document Elements As Window Properties
>
> If you name an element in your HTML document using the id attribute, and if the
>   Window object does not already have a property by that name, the Window object is
>   given a nonenumerable property whose name is the value of the id attribute and whose
>   value is the HTMLElement object that represents that document element.
>
> [..] so this means that the id attributes you use in 
>   your HTML documents become global variables accessible to your scripts
>
> (from JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, Sixth Edition by David Flanagan)

It explains why your stuff works at all.

As @Acyut noted, you use two JavaScript variables: "myCanvas" (brought to life by your HTML declaration of the Canvas HTML element with id attribute as explained in the quote) and the "canvas" variable, which is a reference to the same canvas.

I would suggest to stick to one way how you reference the instance in your code, it is better style.

Comment: Glad I could help you realise this. I was actually unaware that the canvas had to be focused as well. I tried it, didn't work, accidentally clicked the canvas giving it focus and it magically worked!

Answer (score -1):

what you need to do is:

jQ:
`$(document).ready(function(){
      function cool(){
                    $("div").animate({left:'500px'});
      }
     ]);`

i think thats how to do it.

Comment: That's not the way to do it. We are using canvas and the example you just posted moves a div element.